# Find the difference between successive timestamps separately for each day using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe with datetime index:

```
>>> d.head()
Out[29]: 
                         Value 
Time                                                                                                  
2017-04-02 21:11:00.221  1114.73   
2017-04-03 00:01:00.221  1114.73 
2017-04-03 00:01:01.345  1114.73 
2017-04-03 00:01:02.701  1114.10
```

I want to get the successive differences in index times, but for each day separately. I am currently doing this which is incomplete:

```
d['datetime']= d.index
d['datetime_diff']=d['datetime'].diff()
```

This gives me the difference between successive index timestamps, but it doesnt start afresh for each day. I can separate the date from datetime, do groupby on the date and calculate timediffs for each date. There is no set first and last time each day.

After getting these timediffs, I intend to get stats like mean, median, count etc.

Is there a better way to do this? I guess it reduces to a different problem of marking the first value on each day. Now I can get the first value on each day easily using group-by, but that doesn't solve the issue as instead of retrieving the first value, I need an easy way to label the first value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.TimeGrouper`, and group by frequency of `1D`

```
diff = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='1D')).diff()
diff

                         Value
Time                          
2017-04-02 21:11:00.221    NaN
2017-04-03 00:01:00.221    NaN
2017-04-03 00:01:01.345   0.00
2017-04-03 00:01:02.701  -0.63
```

If `df.Time` is not of `DateTime` type, you'll need to convert it:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

---

To get the difference of the index *only*, there's a simpler way - first, `reset_index`, then `groupby` and call `.diff` on only that column. You can also use the `pd.Grouper` with `key=Time` for this.

```
diff = df.reset_index().groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Time', freq='1D')).Time.diff()
diff

0               NaT
1               NaT
2   00:00:01.124000
3   00:00:01.356000
Name: Time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

---

As an aside, if you are interested in day-wise stats, you can groupby and call `.describe`:

```
g = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(level=0, freq='1D'))
g.describe()

           Value                                                          \
           count     mean       std      min       25%      50%      75%   
Time                                                                       
2017-04-02   1.0  1114.73       NaN  1114.73  1114.730  1114.73  1114.73   
2017-04-03   3.0  1114.52  0.363731  1114.10  1114.415  1114.73  1114.73   


                max  
Time                 
2017-04-02  1114.73  
2017-04-03  1114.73
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Just a small addendum- I actually need the differences in Timestamps (index), not the values. My df also has some non-numeric columns, So I adapted your code as this :      { d[ 'diff '] = pd.DataFrame( d.index, index=d.index ).groupby( pd.TimeGrouper( freq='1D' )).diff() }........Do you see a problem with this?

Comment: @dayum Should have realised that's what you wanted. Actually, there is an easier way. Please check my edit.